# Are antibodies removed before blood transfusion

Tags: blood-circulation, antibody, antigen, blood-group, blood-transfusion

I am an O blood group person meaning, I can donate my blood to all as I don't have any Antigen A and B. But my body does contain antibodies A and B right?

If they were along with the donor blood, wouldn't they cause clotting with the recipients blood?

We spent a whole period over this. My teacher said they probably remove the antibody before transfusion, but I couldn't find much info on that. I postulated that these antibodies can not work outside the donor body for some reason.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote from the below.

*Groups and Red Cell Antigens*

by

Laura Dean (page 7). Available at:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2265/

"Red blood cell incompatibility may also occur when the patient's RBC antigens are attacked by antibodies from the donor's plasma. This tends to be a minor problem because of the small amount of antibody present in the donated plasma, which is further diluted on transfusion into the recipient's circulation."

I dont think the antibodies are removed, but in countries with a good medical system I believe the matching blood type is always used.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_hemolytic_transfusion_reaction

Comment: "I dont think the antibodies are removed" But isn't O group still considered universal donor. Thanks for telling me it's only a minor problem

Comment: O is universal donor.